# Vagrant keeps creating unwanted network interfaces

Tags: vagrant

I'm creating a VM definition and I want to specify a single "private_network" on the primary interface of the box (eth0, it's Linux)

Despite having only one config.vm.network statement, I keep getting the desired network set on eth1, while eth0 is assigned an ip from a 10.0.2.0/24 subnet which I have never defined.

How can I prevent this and have my desired 192.168.x.y/24 set on eth0?

Best,
Edoardo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`eth0` is by default used by Vagrant for NAT (VirtualBox NAT networking mode), which allow you to `vagrant ssh` into the box (port forwarding rules - host 2222 <=> guest 22).

That's why you have 2 NICs even though you have only 1 `config.vm.network` in `Vagrantfile`.

I don't think it can be disabled, BUT I am not 100% sure, you may want to look into vagrant source code to dig further.

Comment: sounds reasonable... I'll change my puppet scripts to take this into account

Comment: Correct, Vagrant requires eth0 to be a NAT interface. No way around it currently.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, and I was planning to turn it off in the last step of the provisioning script. Anything wrong with that ?

Comment: No matter what networking you choose, vagrant will always create Adapter 1 as NAT. Refer to https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking#there-is-a-nat-available . There is a hack mentioned here https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/2093

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/questions/957631/how-to-force-vagrant-to-have-a-single-bridged-network-interface

You can try to add the adapter: 1 to the config. Although I still find some problem with it. See if it will help you starts from somewhere.

Example:

config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "Broadcom BCM5709C", adapter: "1", ip: "192.168.x.xx"
You will still have the eth1 which is host-only network...