# why is NAT apdater network still active even I just configure my VM to use public network?

Tags: vagrant

I am now using Vagrant to manage my virtual machine. I configure the VM to use the 'public_network'

my Vagrantfile is as follows:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "precise32"

  config.vm.network "public_network"

  config.vm.synced_folder "data", "/home/vagrant/data"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|

    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
  end

end
```

But when I use 'vagrant up' to start my virtual machine, I find it still use the NAT adapter. Why does that happen?

end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [Vagrant keeps creating unwanted network interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659388/vagrant-keeps-creating-unwanted-network-interfaces)

In short

Vagrant always uses NAT (VirtualBox NAT networking mode), which allow you to `vagrant ssh` into the box (port forwarding rules - host 2222 <=> guest 22).

So in your case, you'll end up having 2 NICs, eth0 for NAT and eth1 for Bridged (Public Network in Vagrant term).

It's just by design :-D