# How to isolate a node on a Vagrant cluster?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, libvirt

I am starting with Vagrant and I am trying to design a cluster with a entry node and other 2 nodes. It should look like:

```
                   --------      eth1            -------- 
           eth0   |        |  17.6.17.10        |        |
 internet ------->| master |-------|------------| slave1 |
                  |        |       | 17.6.17.2  |        |
                   --------        |   eth0      --------
                                   |             
                     17.6.17.0/24  |   eth0      --------
                                   | 17.6.17.3  |        |
                                   |------------| slave2 |
                                                |        |
                                                 --------
```

My Vagrantfile is:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
        config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu1604"

        config.vm.define "master", primary: true do |master|
                master.vm.network "private_network", ip: "17.6.17.10"
                master.vm.hostname = "master"            
        end 

        config.vm.define "slave1" do |slave1|
                slave1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "17.6.17.2"
                slave1.vm.hostname = "slave1"
        end 

        config.vm.define "slave2" do |slave2|
                slave2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "17.6.17.3"
                slave2.vm.hostname = "slave2"
        end
end
```

My configuration create three machines with a shared network and all of them connected to internet. I want to isolate slave1 and slave2 and use master as gateway for internet connections. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to delete the default network routes for each each host and add your own that correspond to the routing configuration you want, cf. the [examples in this writeup](https://www.lab-time.it/2017/11/07/networking-labs-with-vagrant/).

For example to isolate a slave and route the traffic through the master you need to do something like the following:

```
config.vm.define "slave1" do |slave1|
  slave1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "17.6.17.2"
  slave1.vm.hostname = "slave1"
  slave1.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: "route del default"
  slave1.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: "route add default gw 17.6.17.10"
end
```

For the final configuration you need to setup a load balancer and possibly adapt the routing rules, add an additional interface etc on the master, depends exactly on what you want to do, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found a response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22660054/4528653).

It is probable not possible to isolate because Vagrant needs that interface.

Comment: You can change the routing rules to simulate your real word example, please see my answer below!